# What is the proper way to include a PHP Function inside a jQuery append()?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jquery to append another row to a form which uses PHP.
The PHP in the original code uses a function to populate a SELECT input.

Sample of one input from the form;

```
<div class="flex_container">
<div class="flex_label_rpt">Person Type</div>
    <div class="flex_data">
        <select name="person_type[]">
            <?php get_persons_type_list($incident['person_type']) ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
    ... Additional Fields ...
</div>
```

Can I use the same PHP function to populate the new rows that are added using jquery?

I tried something like this:

```
'<select name="person_type[]">'+
    "<?php get_persons_type_list($incident['person_type']) ?>"+
'</select>';
```

But, it just spits out the PHP code, commented out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm pretty good with PHP, but not so much with jquery.

Thanks.

--EDIT-----------------------

```
var maxField_p = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton_p = $('#incident_add_person'); //Add button selector
var wrapper_p = $('#item_row_person'); //Input field wrapper
var fieldHTML_p =
    '<select name="person_type[]">'+
    "<?php get_persons_type_list($incident['person_type']) ?>"+
    '</select>';

var x_p = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

$(addButton_p).click(function(){
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if(x_p < maxField_p){ 
        x_p++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper_p).append(fieldHTML_p); //Add field html
    }
});
```

Comment: PHP run ONLY on the Server. Javascript runs on the Browser (normally)

Comment: Also I dont see anywhere where you are using jQuery to append anything to anything

Comment: well, the update has changed quite a lot your question. Had to delete my answer, you'd need ajax, see the answer by dr.dev

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to include the jquery portion of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate the new row by using an ajax request after creating the form element.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "script.php",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    beforeSend: function() {
        //You can show a preloader here
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    //Hide the preloader
    //Populate the form element 
}).fail(function() { 
    //Show an error message
});
```

Comment: Ok, does the AJAX (or can it) add the results to a variable that I would include in my jquery as it is output back onto the page?

Comment: Your PHP function should return a json with the information that you need to populate the form element. You can use a separate function to populate the element with this information (i.e. populate_element(element_id, data)) and you can also add the results to a js variable but be careful because ajax is asynchronous.